# Ads not showing in Android 8 API 26 using react-native-admob

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I'm using react-native-admob in my app and everything works fine (android and ios) except for certain ads being served once running on Android 8, API 26. Some ads do show but some do not. Here is the error I get consistently from the logs.

I've tried adding the following to my AndroidManifest and using different adUnitId's with no success

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

This is the error

```
 7469 W WebKit  : A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
        02-07 21:28:00.872  7446  7469 W WebKit  : A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
        02-07 21:28:00.878  7333  7333 W Ads     : JS: A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details. (https://ads.rubiconproject.com/ad/8795.js:3)
        02-07 21:28:00.878  7333  7333 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://ads.rubiconproject.com/ad/8795.js (3)
        02-07 21:28:00.878  7333  7333 W Ads     : JS: A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details. (https://ads.rubiconproject.com/ad/8795.js:3)
        02-07 21:28:00.878  7333  7333 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://ads.rubiconproject.com/ad/8795.js (3)
        02-07 21:28:01.240  7446  7469 W WebKit  : A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
        02-07 21:28:01.241  7446  7469 W WebKit  : A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
        02-07 21:28:01.242  7333  7333 W Ads     : JS: A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js, isinvoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details. (https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1:2)
        02-07 21:28:01.242  7333  7333 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1 (2)
        02-07 21:28:01.242  7333  7333 E Ads     : JS: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?_activity_context=false&android_num_video_cache_tasks=0&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_mraid3_sdkVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_scroll_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di_sfv_dinm_dim_nav_navc_dinmo_ipdof_gls_xSeconds&eid=318483745%2C318479959&format=320x50_mb&heap_free=13542264&heap_max=268435456&heap_total=30428640&js=afma-sdk-a-v12451000.12451000.0&msid=com.zumobi.android.motortrend&preqs=0&request_pkg=com.sbugert.rnadmob.ReactPublisher...vity_context=false&android_num_video_cache_tasks=0&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_mraid3_sdkVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_scroll_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di_sfv_dinm_dim_nav_navc_dinmo_ipdof_gls_xSeconds&eid=318483745%252C318479959&format=320x50_mb&heap_free=13542264&heap_max=268435456&heap_total=30428640&js=afma-sdk-a-v12451000.12451000.0&msid=com.zumobi.android.motortrend&preqs=0&request_pkg=com.sbugert.rnadmob.ReactPublisherAdView&scroll_index=-1&seq_num=1&target_api=26' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. (https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1:2)
        02-07 21:28:01.242  7333  7333 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?_activity_context=false&android_num_video_cache_tasks=0&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_mraid3_sdkVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_scroll_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di_sfv_dinm_dim_nav_navc_dinmo_ipdof_gls_xSeconds&eid=318483745%2C318479959&format=320x50_mb&heap_free=13542264&heap_max=268435456&heap_total=30428640&js=afma-sdk-a-v12451000.12451000.0&msid=com.zumobi.android.motortrend&preqs=0&request_pkg=com.sbugert.rnadmob.ReactPublisher...vity_context=false&android_num_video_cache_tasks=0&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_mraid3_sdkVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_scroll_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di_sfv_dinm_dim_nav_navc_dinmo_ipdof_gls_xSeconds&eid=318483745%252C318479959&format=320x50_mb&heap_free=13542264&heap_max=268435456&heap_total=30428640&js=afma-sdk-a-v12451000.12451000.0&msid=com.zumobi.android.motortrend&preqs=0&request_pkg=com.sbugert.rnadmob.ReactPublisherAdView&scroll_index=-1&seq_num=1&target_api=26' wasloaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be servedover HTTPS.", source: https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1 (2)
        02-07 21:28:01.242  7333  7333 W Ads     : JS: A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js, isinvoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details. (https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1:2)
        02-07 21:28:01.242  7333  7333 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/8795/53518/246116-43.js?&cb=0.022579154963838777&tk_st=1&rp_s=c&p_exp=1&p_pos=btf&p_screen_res=360x640&ad_slot=53518_43&rp_secure=1 (2)
```

I expect the ads to show on Android 8, API 26 and above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your script not clear enough to get a help,update your Question to be more clear

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll update and post the whole error

Comment: did you solve this error?

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 I remember solving it from the ad server side. I'll see if I can trace what we did and post an answer. I didn't change anything code wise though

Comment: it would be great, thanks.